# Refused to execute script because its MIME type is not executable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, sharepoint

I get following Errorcode when executing my ajax request .

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://inet/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ToDos')/items/?$select=Title&callback=jQuery31002972444065120874_1476256852529&_=1476256852530'
>   because its MIME type ('application/atom+xml') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

`http://inet/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ToDos')/items/?$select=Title&callback=jQuery31002972444065120874_1476256852529&_=1476256852530 contains xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" data`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        execOperation();

        function execOperation() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://inet/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ToDos')/items/?$select=Title",
                method: "GET",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType : "jsonp",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/jason;odata=verbose" ,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    document.write((data));
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    document.write('!!! ERROR !!!<br>');
                    document.write(err);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help .

Comment: Is `application/jason` a valid `MIME` type? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to display the data from the table ToDos

Comment: `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: it s at a local Server ... you can t reach it outside of the network

Comment: Does the remote server (inet) support JSONP? (It feels like you are trying to fetch an RSS feed using JSONP, which according to my knowledge doesn't work that way. The remote server has to be JSONP compatible.